# Post to Python view after Javascript validation in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I have a template that has a form with two input boxes. The problem is that I need to ensure that only one of either box has a filled value. That is, one text box should be empty. Since Django doesn't provide this kind of an OR mechanism, I am checking this through Javascript in the template:

```
function validateData() {
    if ($("#email").val() && $("#cellno").val()){
        alert("Please Enter either E-Mail Address or Cell Number");
    } else {
        alert("Form submitted successfully");
        // redirect to view_2
    }
}
```

The issue is that I want to send the data from the textbox to view_2. How can I send the value of the textbox and also perform the validation? Without the JS validation I could have simply added the url to the form action.

Comment: Have a look at django forms: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/

Comment: Have another look at my question.

Comment: You are missing the closing `}` for your function. My brain immediatelly return a parse error when I read that code :)

Comment: @randomnessrandomly Django provides a mechanism to verify the data through forms, cf my link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'Django doesn't provide this kind of or mechanism'. If you're using Django forms in your view, you can write a clean method that [validates fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False)
    cell = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=20)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()
        if cleaned_data.get('email') and cleaned_data.get('cell'):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please select either E-mail address or cell number, but not both")
        return cleaned_data
```

Comment: I like this better than my answer. Clear solution with Django.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you should attach your function to the `submit` event and prevent submitting when validation fails.

Maybe something like this:

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
    if ($("#email").val() && $("#cellno").val()){
        alert("Please Enter either E-Mail Address or Cell Number");
        event.preventDefault(); // this prevents the submitting.
    } else {
        alert("Form submitted successfully");
    }
});
```

Comment: @Alasdair Oh, thank you. You are certainly right. The form should not be submitted in the if branch. I am editing that right now.